# Reuse HTML when building create/update/view pages in angular2

Tags: angular

I'm building an Angular2 APP with CRUD functionaries. I've started with Create page and when trying to build the Update/View pages, I'm trying to use the same HTML. So I ended up using template having `[disabled]` attribute to handle which mode I'm in.

I'd like if there is a better approach (best practices) when building CRUD pages?

Answer (score 0):

you can create components that render as labels or inputs depending on the mode you are in. you can also reuse some more of the html you are typing (i.e. the title of the field, or some validation messages). probably not a bad idea if you design/implement it carefully.